# HTTP CONNECT Tunnel reply with BAD Request (400)

Tags: java, apache, http

I have this code for HTTP Tunnel

```
private static void doTunnelHandshake(Socket conn, String proxyHost, int proxyPort, String host, int port) throws IOException {

    String msg = "CONNECT " + host + ":" + port + " HTTP/1.1\n" + "Host: https://" + proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort + "\r\n" + "User-Agent: " + sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent+ "\r\n\r\n";

OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

byte b[];
try {
    /*
     * We really do want ASCII7 -- the http protocol doesn't change with
     * locale.
     */
    b = msg.getBytes("ASCII7");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
    /*
     * If ASCII7 isn't there, something serious is wrong, but Paranoia
     * Is Good (tm)
     */
    b = msg.getBytes();
}

out.write(b);
out.flush();

/*
 * We need to store the reply so we can create a detailed error message
 * to the user.
 */
byte reply[] = new byte[200];
int replyLen = 0;
int newlinesSeen = 0;
boolean headerDone = false; /* Done on first newline */

InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

while (newlinesSeen < 2) {
    int i = in.read();
    if (i < 0) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected EOF from proxy");
    }
    if (i == '\n') {
        headerDone = true;
        ++newlinesSeen;
    } else if (i != '\r') {
        newlinesSeen = 0;
        if (!headerDone && replyLen < reply.length) {
            reply[replyLen++] = (byte) i;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Converting the byte array to a string is slightly wasteful in the
 * case where the connection was successful, but it's insignificant
 * compared to the network overhead.
 */
String replyStr;
try {
    replyStr = new String(reply, 0, replyLen, "ASCII7");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
    replyStr = new String(reply, 0, replyLen);
}



/* We asked for HTTP/1.0, so we should get that back */
if (!replyStr.startsWith("HTTP/1.0 200")) {
    throw new IOException("Unable to tunnel for " + host + ":" + port + ".  TunnelProxy returns \"" + replyStr + "\"");
} 

/* tunneling Handshake was successful! */
}
```

but apache replies

> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution found!**

Missing a `\r`

```
String msg = "CONNECT " + host + ":" + port + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: https://" + proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort + "\r\n" + "User-Agent: " + sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent+ "\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: That is most amazing since the RFC requires `\n` to be treated just like `\r\n`. Perhaps the state machine in question doesn't like intermixing the two.

Comment: The previous version workde well, now after a security patche we have got this issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's a theory: Your `CONNECT` call is malformed in that the [`Host` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) is overspecified; it is - in this case - supposed to contain not a fully qualified URL but a hostname and (if necessary) a port. the `CONNECT` and `Host` should also match. The proxy host and port are irrelevant in this case, as you already opened the socket. Your innitial request should (according to [RFC 7231, sec. 4.3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.6) look like this:

```
CONNECT host:port HTTP/1.1
Host: host:port
```

On a related note, you can strip the ASCII7-stuff. The "control codes" for HTTP may work in US-ASCII, but message bodies may not. Even worse, select headers may contain UTF8. I'm also a bit puzzled as you are sending out a request in HTTP/1.1 while expecting HTTP/1.0 in response in your code.

Comment: the server replies with HTTP/1.0 200...maybe I can add HTTP/1.1 200

Comment: Could be the peer only supports 1.0. Is this an academic assignment?

Comment: No...real production